# Linux/Unix Syslog writes unwanted characters to log message- using ACE

Tags: linux, rsyslog, ace

I am sending log messages to linux syslog in multithreaded environment, using ACE function: **ACE_Log_Msg().**

In about 5% of the log messages, an unwanted extra characters appear in my syslog output.
The code I am using to send log messages to ACE is as follows:

```
#include "ace/Log_Msg.h"

ACE_Mutex syslog_mtx;
int ACE_TMAIN (int argc, ACE_TCHAR *argv[])
{
  ACE_Guard<ACE_Mutex> mtx (syslog_mtx);

  ACE_LOG_MSG->open (argv[0], ACE_Log_Msg::SYSLOG, ACE_TEXT ("syslogTest"));

  ACE_DEBUG ((LM_INFO, ACE_TEXT (L"my log message\n")));

  ACE_LOG_MSG->open (argv[0], ACE_Log_Msg::STDERR, ACE_TEXT ("syslogTest"));

  return 0;
}
```

And the log messages I see in syslog looks like this:

```
Oct 9 15:25:20 SYSLOG ~[62266]: my log message
Oct 9 15:25:20 SYSLOG ``[62266]: 6]: my log message
```

As you can see, extra characters: **~, ``, 6]:**   seem to be inserted where the application name/process ID appears in syslog format.
I can't seem to understand the possible origin of that bug. I will be glad to hear suggestions for the possible cause.

Comment: `.... ACE_TEXT ("L"my log message\n")` ? That really compiles? Is that a feature of `ACE_DEBUG` ? Readers need the smallest amount of code that will reproduce the problem. They will need to compile it to see the problem, so you'll need to include a `main()` and any other `#includes` needed to demonstrate the problem (in hopefully 10 lines of code). Please read about [Minimal,Complete,Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and improve your Q. Good luck.

Comment: Don't think there was any need for mutex locking.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `L` before `"my log message"`, ACE_TEXT already handles that

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Could the problem lie with this line of code:    ACE_Guard<ACE_Mutex> mtx (syslog_mtx);  ? maybe this is a mulithread safety issue?

Comment: No, maybe it is a bug in the ACE library, try to run it within a debugger and check what happens

Comment: Also, It seems that the title "syslogTest" was supposed to be added to the syslog format in every log message, but it doesn't seem to happen. instead of that the default program name SYSLOG appears in the log messages. Why is that?

Comment: Maybe a bug, try to run it within the debugger and see what happens, you have all the code, when you have fixes, please open a PR at https://github.com/DOCGroup/ACE_TAO